# Is the final comma in Rust struct definitions necessary?

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
struct User {
    user: String,
    email: String,
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain about it. The trailing comma after the `email` field struck me as odd, so I tried this:

```
struct User {
    user: String,
    email: String // no comma
}
```

The compiler still doesn't complain. Is there a difference or are the two scenarios completely equivalent?

Comment: languages often allow trailing commas kind so you can add new lines without modifying previous lines. it makes diffs clearer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The last comma is purely optional in `struct` definitions. This is pure convenience; it allows you to leave that trailing comma in, so you do not have to go back and modify a line if you add an additional field, delete a field or change their order.

It also, coincidentally, makes code generation from macros easier, as your codegen macro no longer has to care about keeping track of whether you are on the last generated field.

The **one time** when you'll see a trailing comma being mandatory is in macros like the `diesel` [`table!`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/macro.table.html) macro, and the reason is down to the [macro invocation structure](https://docs.diesel.rs/src/diesel/macros/mod.rs.html#459) chosen by the `diesel` developers.

Comment: Yes, _pure convenience_, but I'd say recommended. Not for adding additional fields, but imagine you'd like to swap two fields for example, remove them, etc.

Comment: "Adding" is loosely interepreted as modifying, really. I'll edit the answer to make that obvious. Levenshtein is fun, they said :-)

Answer (score 3):

Have to say that you are an acute observer. They are equivalent according to [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/structs.html):

> StructFields :
>
> StructField (, StructField)* ,?

It is that way for convenience reason: be able to add or remove lines without touching previous ones.

Here's a counter-example. In languages that don't have such convenience, people may choose to format the code in unusual ways to achieve virtually the same, such as:

```hs
data Person = Person
    { firstName :: String
    , lastName  :: String
    , age       :: Int
    }
```

I like an optional trailing comma more.

Answer (score -2):

Adding a trailing comma to make it easier to add a field in the future goes against the XP "[YAGNI](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/You-arent-gonna-need-it)" You Ain't Gonna Need It principal.  Planning for some future enhancement is a waste of time because by the time "the future" arrives the requirements for that enhancement will have changed from what I, in my infinitely wise foresight, thought they would be way back when.
On the other hand I can see the comma being useful to make "diff" output less "noisy".

According to people on [this rust-lang.org thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-would-one-put-comma-after-the-last-field/14614/5), the trailing comma on the last field makes automatic code generation easier since it doesn't have to deal with the "is this the last field?" question. Also something about macro generation that I don't understand at this point in my oxidation education.
The comma also makes it easier to rearrange the order of fields in the struct, but again, planning for the future should wait for the future.

Comment: Not a rust coder, but I feel like saying YAGNI here is a bit much. The reason why YAGNI is good and important is to prevent developers from investing time and effort where it does not belong. More specifically, it prevents you from drowning your code in unneeded complexity. A trailing comma is hardly unneeded complexity.

Comment: The trailing comma is appended by rustfmt automatically, which you should run anyway, so no additional effort. And diverging from [the official Rust style](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/HEAD/src/doc/style-guide/src#trailing-commas) is much worse and needs much stronger reason than an arguable case of YAGNI.

Comment: @davidalayachew:  After some thought I'll say you're both on-the-money.  Thanks for the input.